# Which is the best type for counting weight

Tags: c#

I need to count weight without rounding. Which is the best type for count weight
float , double or decimal.

```
float   weight=0.333f;
double  weight=0.333;
decimal weight=0.333m;
```

My weight will be from 0.000 till 999.000;

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "rounding"?

Comment: I read that double has some rounding problems

Comment: So with double am i ok?

Comment: When working with fixed *decimal point* (`3` digits after it in your case) choose `decimal` (it is your case). When working with fixed *significant digits* (e.g. `999.1`, `78.56`, `5.366`, `0.2563` - `4` digits) the choice is `double`

Comment: do you only have 3 digits after the decimal for precision?  If that is the case, then the best way to get 100% accuracy is to use an int

Comment: If you want exact values, you'll need to use `decimal`. Otherwise, you'll run into precision issues. This is usually only a problem for something like currency. I can't imagine 13.9999999997 instead of 14 posing a problem for weight.

Comment: _My weight will be from 0.000 till 999.000_ Decimal then.

Comment: all 3 floats, doubles, and decimals will suffice for most practical purposes though, and are probably easier to work with than the int.  `decimal` has the highest precision, if that's what you're looking for, and it's purpose is for money, which is very similar to your weight calculations.

Comment: To give you an idea of the problem with mapping decimals to IEEE floating point numbers... `0.1d` isn't exactly `1/10`: `Enumerable.Repeat(0.1d, 10).Sum() == 1d` is `false`. This can lead to all sorts of accounting problems.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `int` in the range 0 - 999000. Add a decimal separator during the output.